# Traefik Middleware Regex - How to append character on exact match?

Tags: regex, docker, traefik

Use Case:
Site is accessible with `/foo/`.
In Case, a user calls for `/foo`, I want a permanent redirect to '/foo/' by traefik middleware.

Tried around a little bit with `ReplacePathRegex` Middleware.

- `traefik.http.middlewares.foo-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.regex=(/foo)$$`
- `traefik.http.middlewares.foo-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.replacement=$$1/`

Unfortunately, this won't work.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://community.containo.us/t/middleware-to-add-the-if-needed/1895/6):

```
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix.chain.middlewares=strip-prefix-1,strip-prefix-2
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix-1.redirectregex.regex=^(https?://[^/]+/[a-z0-9_]+)$$
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix-1.redirectregex.replacement=${1}/
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix-1.redirectregex.permanent=true
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix-2.stripprefixregex.regex=/[a-z0-9_]+
```

Comment: just copy and paste it with mappint the middlewares to the router gives me:

`Invalid interpolation format for "labels" option in service "foo": "traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix-1.redirectregex.regex=^(https?://[^/]+/[a-z0-9_]+)$"`

Comment: When I ran into this error, it was because of the unescaped "$" try changing to "$$" to escape the character. See the [docker configuration example](https://www.bookstack.cn/read/traefik-2.2-en/03b1c5c0cea6bc9d.md)

Answer (score 0):

here is the yaml version based on [@wp78de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8291949/wp78de) answer

```
http:
  routers:
      redirect-router-cv:
        entryPoints: web-secure
        middlewares: 
          - redirect-middleware-add-slash
          - redirect-middleware-add-slash-helper
        rule: Host(`example.com`)
        service: noop@internal
        tls:
          certResolver: default
  middlewares:
      redirect-middleware-add-slash:
        redirectRegex:
          regex: ^(https?://[^/]+/[a-z0-9_]+)$$
          replacement: $${1}/
          permanent: true
      redirect-middleware-add-slash-helper:
        stripPrefixRegex:
          regex: /[a-z0-9_]+
```